# Why findInLine(token) works but hasNext(token) doesn't

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to understand the Scanner class and its methods. I have understood how `findInLine` method works but I can't understand how `hasNext(String)` and `next(String)` methods work.

Here's my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        hasNextTest("\\d");
        //findInLineTest("\\d");
    }

    public static void findInLineTest(String token) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input source string :");
        System.out.flush();
        String str = null;
        while (( str = s.findInLine(token)) != null) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        System.out.flush();
        s.close();
    }

    public static void hasNextTest(String token) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input source string :");
        System.out.flush();
        System.out.println(s.hasNext(token));
//      while (s.hasNext(token)) {

//          System.out.println(s.next(token));
//      }
        System.out.flush();
        s.close();
    }

}
```

The part I can't understand is if I pass to the scanner String "abcd12345abcd" or say any other String that has digits, the method `hasNext("\\d")` doesn't return true. It doesn't `return true` for any pattern and Strings for which the `hasNext(String)` method should return true. I'm not using the Scanner object correctly but can someone help me find the mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: *"It doesn't return true for any pattern and Strings for which the hasNext(String) method should return true."* It is true for "abcd12345abcd" and it is obivously false for `\\d`, because the next token is not a number.

Comment: Here's my output - Input source string :
abcd1234abcd
false

Comment: Is "abcd1234abcd" a number? Doesn't look like one. Does the documentation of `hasNext(String)` indicate that it looks for something that can match the pattern *inside* the next token, like `findInLine` does?

Comment: Oh I get it now. It doesn't look inside the whole String. But if my pattern is "12" and input String is "12 12" it prints 12 two times as expected. But if I supply "12 34 12" as input and "12" as pattern then the only match is 12 once. So is this method first dividing the input strings into tokens by splitting them between spaces and then looking for a match and the while loop fails when the next token is 34.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks Tom. This is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasNext(pattern)` attempts to match the specified pattern against entire tokens. The string "abcd12345abcd" does not have delimiters, so it constitutes one token. Your pattern looks for a token consisting of a single digit, which obviously isn't going to match.

`findInLine(pattern)`, on the other hand, attempts to find a pattern anywhere in the line, so the first found digit would match.